# Precedence/weight to a column using FREETEXTTABLE in dymnamic TSQL

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search, ranking

I have dynamic sql that perform paging and a full text search using CONTAINSTABLE which works fine. Problem is I would like to use FREETEXTTABLE but weight the rank of some colums over others

Here is my orginal sql and the ranking weight I would like to integrate
(I have changed names for privacy reasons)

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 10 Things.ID, ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC ) AS Row FROM [Things]
    INNER JOIN 
        CONTAINSTABLE([Things],(Features,Description,Address),
            'ISABOUT("cow" weight (.9), "cow" weight(.1))') AS KEY_TBL 
    ON [Properties].ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY] 
    WHERE TypeID IN (91, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53) 
        AND
        dbo.FN_CalcDistanceBetweenLocations(51.89249, -8.493376, 
        Latitude, Longitude) <= 2.5 
    ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC ) x 
WHERE x.Row BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Here is what I would like to integrate

```
select sum(rnk) as weightRankfrom
From
(select 
    Rank * 2.0 as rnk, 
    [key] 
from freetexttable(Things,Address,'cow')
union all 
select 
    Rank * 1.0 as rnk, 
    [key] 
from freetexttable(Things,(Description,Features),'cow')) as t 
group by [key] 
order by weightRankfrom desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the algorithm used by the freetext engine (`FREETEXTTABLE`) has no way to specify the significance of the various input columns. If this is critical, you may need to consider using a different product for your freetext needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column with the concatenation of:

1. Less_important_field &
2. More_important_field & More_important_field (2x)

This might look really stupid, but it's actually what BM25F does to simulate structured documents.  The only downside of this hack-implementation is that you can't actually dynamically change the weight.  It bloats up the table a bit, but not necessarily the index, which should only need counts.